# django orm how to get the sum of the first element of an array field?

Tags: python, django

I have the following `django` model for `postgres`. Assume `metric_vals` are non-empty arrays. Is there a way of getting the sum of all first values of `metric_vals`?

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    metric_vals = ArrayField(models.FloatField(null=False), null=False, default=list)
```

I tried the following but resulted in error:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models import Sum

SampleModel.objects.aggregate(Sum('metric_vals__0'))
```

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function sum(double precision[]) does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a table like

```
create table metrics_table
(
    id serial not null constraint metrics_pk primary key,
    metrics double precision[]
);
```

the SQL query

```
select sum(metrics[1]) from metrics_table;
```

works.

You will probably need the [`RawSQL` annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions#//apple_ref/Class/django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL).

Based on this, off the top of my head, something like

```
SampleModel.objects
  .annotate(first_metric=RawSQL('metric_vals[1]'))
  .aggregate(first_metric_sum=Sum('first_metric'))
```

might do the trick.

Comment: RawSQL required a params input, other than that it worked perfectly! thank you!